# Trying to install System.Random on stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm using stack 1.6.1.  In `src/Main.hs` I start with

```
module Main where

import System.IO
import System.Random
...
```

I do not use anything from System.Random at this time.

When I run `stack ghci` I get

```
/Users/mkaravan/end2end/Music/music/src/Main.hs:4:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
4 | import System.Random
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've had no luck with any of the following commands:

```
stack install System.Random
stack install system.random
stack install random
```

I get this error:

```
>>> stack install System.Random
Error parsing targets: Directory not found: System.Random
```

How do I get System.Random to run in Stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to add `random` to the dependencies section in your `package.yaml` (or if you are not using hpack, to `build-depends` in `*.cabal`).  This tells stack that the package depends on the random package, which contains the `System.Random` module.

Comment: That works, my *.cabal looks like:
`
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , random
`

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most straightforward command is `stack ghci --package random`. But in theory `stack install random` should have worked as well. However, since you haven't included the output from that call, it's not clear what didn't work with it.

Comment: Edited above.  `stack install random` yields no response.  `stack ghci --package random` runs the program though.