# How to get rid of annoying startup message from stack ghci?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm using `stack ghci` to start my REPL, based on the answer I got for my [question on how to import a module installed with `stack`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618016/haskell-cant-import-system-random). This works fine, but I get initially a warning message *Note: No local targets specified, so a plain ghci will be started with no package hiding or package options.*, followed by a bunch of suggestions about package hiding and options. My guess is that this is because I have not used `stack init` to setup a project, since I am still in the "playing around and learning" state and don't want a project yet. I have not found an explanation about the meaning of 'no local targets', but the effect to start a plain ghci is exactly what I want at that point. Is there a way to suppress this message? I looked at `stack --help`, but could not find something suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `Note` (not warning) suggests, a plain ghci is started, which is rather uncommon situation when working with `stack`.

```
~$ stack ghci

Note: No local targets specified, so a plain ghci will be started with no package hiding or package options.

      You are using snapshot: lts-14.12

      If you want to use package hiding and options, then you can try one of the following:

      * If you want to start a different project configuration than /home/username/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml, then you can use stack init to create a new stack.yaml for the packages in the
        current directory. 

      * If you want to use the project configuration at /home/username/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml, then you can add to its 'packages' field.

Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/haskell-stack-ghci/2a3bbd58/ghci-script
Prelude>
```

This means though that all you need to do to get the same behavior without the `Note` is just start ghci manually in the context of global stack environment:

```
~$ stack exec -- ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude>
```

In case that you want to make sure some package is installed for "playing around and learning" in the ghci session you can supply them as `--package` arguments

```
~$ stack exec --package massiv -- ghci
atomic-primops> using precompiled package
cabal-doctest > using precompiled package
scheduler     > using precompiled package
massiv        > using precompiled package
Completed 4 action(s).
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Data.Massiv.Array
Prelude Data.Massiv.Array>
```

Answer (score 0):

`stack exec --ghci` as in lehins's answer did not work for me, but `stack exec ghci` did.

Comment: It's not `exec --ghci`, it's `exec  --  ghci`.

Comment: Indeed. Here `--` denotes the “end of options“ (except for `echo`). See [this explanation](https://www.devhowto.dev/cmdline/argument-syntax.html#end-of-options).